# Enforcement of password policy

Tags: security

Many operating systems enforce certain constraints on passwords such as changing the password every n days etc.

Some also enforce a policy such as "the new password must differ in at least n characters from your previous password(s)".

My question is: how can you enforce such a policy without actually storing the passwords in clear text. Specifically: If I do not want to store the passwords in clear text but rather als (salted) hashes, how would I enforce this kind of poilicy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can check that the password doesn't match the last N passwords by comparing it to old hashes, but anything that goes down to character level cannot be easily applied.

In theory, if you really wanted to do it, you could probably bruteforce one or two characters difference. (just hash all possible 2-character changes from the new password) But given how new algorithms rely on hashing being slow, this is not realistic with modern password hashing functions.

Just to be clear, I'm assuming that clear-text is the same as locally-encrypted for all practical purposes. Some systems will encrypt and save your original password, so they can verify it or allow recovery. Of course that only provides few benefits of hashing.